# ionic app splash screen are not shown

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have been trying over and over to add a splashscreen to my Ionic App
with this configuration the icons does work but the `splashscreen` aren't working. It's displaying a blank screen, not even the `cordova` default `splashscreen.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.toggle423609" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>Toggle</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com.com/">
      Your Name Here
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />

  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" height="1136" width="640"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" height="1334" width="750"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" height="2208" width="1242"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" height="1242" width="2208"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" height="1536" width="2048"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" height="768" width="1024"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" height="2048" width="1536"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" height="1024" width="768"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" height="960" width="640"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" height="480" width="320"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: Have you installed the plugin to your project? cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen

Comment: Plugin "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" already installed on and
Plugin "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" already installed on ios its not working

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. First try readding your plugin:

   ```
   $ ionic plugin remove cordova-plugin-splashscreen
   $ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
   ```
2. Then edit the `splash` image in your `resources` folder.
3. Run `$ ionic resources --splash` in CLI
4. Rebuild `$ ionic build android` and run your app

Check [Ionic documentation - Icon and Splash Screen Image Generation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html)

If this is not working, you should remove and readd the platform, on which you experiencing the problem.

```
$ cordova platform remove android (or ios)
$ cordova platform add android (or ios)
```

Comment: D:\nodejs\Toggle>cordova platfotm remove android
Error: Cordova does not know platfotm; try `cordova help` for a list of all the
available commands.

Comment: Is this exactly what the CLI gives back, after `cordova platform remove android`? Are you on Mac?

Comment: Worth noting that removing/reinstalling the platform will delete the custom splashscreen images you had.

Comment: Doing only the first step worked for me! I didn't have "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" plugin added. While on iOS it still showed the splash screen briefly (even without the plugin), and Android - it didn't. Running command in the first step fixed the issue ` ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen`

Answer (score 11):

**Here is your answer!!**

If you are using Cordova 6.4.0 (hit `cordova -v` in your terminal to check the version), you will face this issue(the icons and splash screens won't generate after build)

In order to resolve the issue, you have two options :

1. change the word **density** to **qualifier** in your config.xml. For eg. put

`<icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" qualifier="ldpi"/>` in place of `<icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>`. Build the project. Will work.

2. Just install the cordova version 6.3.1 by hitting `npm install -g cordova@6.3.1` in your terminal. Remove and then add the platform, further build it. Works like a charm!!.

Regards!!  :p

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted but it fixed my problem. I've been trying for 4 days to figure this out and all I had to do is update my Cordova.

Comment: yes it work. change from "density" to "qualifier" for splashscree

Answer (score 6):

After remove and add cordova

```
   $ cordova platform remove android (or ios)
   $ cordova platform add android (or ios)
```

You will get a `/res` folder with your icons and splash screens. Copy the content from `/res` and paste into `platfomrs/android/res`, this will replace the standard icon and splash screens.

Then build your app and you will get your custom images.

I used ionic tab template, without changes.

Comment: For me on ionic2 now, the files were not named `drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png` but `screen.png` and stored in separate folders named `drawable-port-ldpi` for instance. Had to copy-paste them and rename manually

Answer (score 5):

My Splash-Screen wasn't showing up either (Ionic 3). I found this [Link](http://www.codingandclimbing.co.uk/blog/ionic-2-fix-splash-screen-white-screen-issue) to be very helpfull. These entries in the `config.xml` did the trick for me:

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true"/>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000"/>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

since 07 Nov 2016. Cordova 6.4.0 released with new android version - android@6.1.0.

Most likely you are using android@5 in your cordova(or the old version of android).
Try updating/install the new version of cordova android.

To upgrade:
cordova platform update android@6.1.0

To add it explicitly:
cordova platform add android@6.1.0

https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2016/11/07/android-release.html
https://cordova.apache.org/blog/

Answer (score 1):

We were trying to update ionic app's splash screen using below configuration system but  failed :

`Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.11 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Xcode 8.1 Build version 8B62`

We were able to generate splash screen and fix the issue in below configuration system:

`Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version: CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local: Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.6.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.1 Build version 8B62`

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem, i solved manually by going to path `MY_PROJECT\platforms\android\res` and delete `drawable*` and `mipmap*` and then copy `drawable*` and `mipmap*` from `MY_PROJECT\res` and then re-build project again

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" plugin installed (in the `plugins/` folder or by running `ionic cordova plugins` (for Ionic v3+) or `ionic plugins` command (older versions of Ionic).

If it's not there run:
`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen` (Ionic v1 - v2)
`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen` (Ionic v3+)

Without the plugin iOS will still show the splash screen briefly, but Android wouldn't.

Comment: Note, if you have a ton of plugins try `ionic plugins | grep splash` (Ionic v1-v2) or `ionic cordova plugins | grep splash` (Ionic v3+) to find out of the plugin is installed. If it is - you will see the output similar to the following `cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"`

Answer (score 0):

add Splash Screen Cordova plugins in your app using the following command

```
    $ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
    $npm install --save @ionic-native/splash-screen
```

Add following line in you **config.xml** file

```
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

Also, Remove `SplashScreen.hide()` in **app.component.ts** file

More details with example visit: https://answerdone.blogspot.com/2018/02/ionic-3-splash-screen-plugins.html